# Make header stay topmost?

Tags: php, css

Anyone got a quick solution?

I have tried to edit it on my header(.pxtm), on my .css file and on my .php file.

I would like to share my code with you, so you fast can edit, but I'm not sure which one I should include, and if I include it all, there would be way too much code on this question.

Here is my site: http://csgochat.info/aboutus.php

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution: add a `z-index` to your header.

```
#blab_top_bar {
    z-index: 99;
}
```